# Input field with a clear button. Can't clear the state

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a generic Input component with a clear button but I'm having trouble with clearing the state from within the component itself when the parent is holding the state.

Setting the ref value to '' doesn't trigger the onChange event.

Don't know how to call props.onChange in the Input component since I'm using typescript in my project and onChange expects event type.

Here is a recreation of my problem https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-voice-rwy2ms?file=/src/App.js

Type something in the input field.
Press Clear.
The input field sets to empty but the state in parent is not reset.

**update**
Some answers are recommending a clearCallbackFunction or sendind setText down to the child.
The input component will be part of a component library so I don't want the parent to care about the clear function and ut would be nice to not add props to the input field.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-darkness-pk4dvg?file=/src/Input.js). I wouldn't recommend using `useRef` for this. Instead, pass the value and setter both down to the `Input` component. Then, the clear button can set the value to and empty string.

Input.js

```
const Input = (props) => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    props.setText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={props.text} onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={() => props.setText("")}>Clear</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Input;
```

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Input from "./Input";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Input text={text} setText={setText} />
      <p>The current state is: {text}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This would in practice work yes. But updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your button to revert the `text` state back to an empty string, you'll want the onClick trigger to call the `setText()` function

```
<button type='button' onClick={() => setText('')}>Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The onChange props callback can be used to clear both,

```
import { useRef } from "react";
const Input = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const handleClear = (e) => {
    props.onChange(e);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={ref} {...props} />
      <button
        onClick={handleClear}
      >
        Clear
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Input;
```

Comment: This sounds like a good idea but typescript gets really angry "Argument of type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'."

Answer (score 0):

You are just clearing the value of input in that component which will not affect the state in parent component.

Solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-fast-s4l5vz

Comment: Links are bound to become stale and inactive. Please put the important lines of code in the answer